# Inherited member becomes null after initialize

Tags: java, javafx

I made a simple FX program to replicate the problem I am seeing. I have a `TestController` that extends `AbstractBar` which extends `AbstractFoo`. After calling the `initialize()` method, a simple GUI displays with a button. I am expecting a "Hello World!" message to print to the console when the button is pressed, but I am getting a null value instead. Why does this happen and how do I fix this?

```
Expected result: Hello World!
Button result: null
Button result: null
```

Main.java

```
package com.test.main;

import com.test.gui.TestController;

import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;

public class Main {
    private static TestController controller;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fxml = "/gui/Simple.fxml";
        String content = "Hello World!";
        
        new JFXPanel();
        
        controller = new TestController();
        controller.initialize(fxml, content);
        System.out.println("Expected result: " + controller.getContent());
    }

}
```

TestController.java

```
package com.test.gui;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class TestController extends AbstractBar {

    @FXML
    private void testButton() {
        System.out.println("Button result: " + super.getContent());
    }
}
```

AbstractBar.java

```
package com.test.gui;

public abstract class AbstractBar extends AbstractFoo {

    @Override
    public void initialize(String fxml, String content) {
        // Do stuff.
        super.initialize(fxml, content);
    }
}
```

AbstractFoo.java

```
package com.test.gui;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public abstract class AbstractFoo {
    protected String fxml;
    protected String content;
    protected Stage stage;
    protected Parent root;
    
    public void initialize(String fxml, String content) {
        this.fxml = fxml;
        this.content = content;
        
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(this.getClass().getResource(fxml));
            
            try {
                this.root = loader.load();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            this.stage = new Stage();
            this.stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            this.stage.show();
        });
    }
    
    public String getContent() {
        return this.content;
    }
}
```

Simple.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>


<BorderPane fx:id="root" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.test.gui.TestController">
   <center>
      <Button fx:id="button" text="Click me!" onAction="#testButton" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: The `TestController` instance you create is not the same one as created by the `FXMLLoader`, which is the one "linked" with the loaded FXML file. This is also a very strange way to initialize your application. You use `JFXPanel` to, I assume, start the JavaFX runtime. You should extend `javafx.application.Application` and launch your application "normally".

Comment: *”I am expecting ‘Hello World’ to be printed to the console when the button is pressed”*.  Why would you expect that? `content` is never initialised in the actual controller instance.

Comment: Wow, that is correct... I didn't realize that the `FXMLLoader` instantiated its own controller. thank you!

Comment: @Hydron None of the basic examples in any intro tutorial or documentation would work otherwise. (And in any other case, really. How would you expect the `FXMLLoader` to know about the instance you created, and use it as the controller? What if you had created two instances? How would it know which to use?) It’s not really clear what you are doing here. What’s wrong with using the library the way it was intended to be used?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by the comments, it is correct that the `FXMLLoader` is not using the same controller instance I am expecting. The simple fix is to remove the `fx:controller` attribute from the fxml file. and add `loader.setController(this)` to AbstractFoo. Now everything works as expected, what a big oversight...

```
com.test.gui.TestController@568bf312
Expected result: Hello World!
com.test.gui.TestController@568bf312
Button result: Hello World!
```

Simple.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>


<BorderPane fx:id="root" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
   <center>
      <Button fx:id="button" text="Click me!" onAction="#testButton" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

AbstractFoo.java

```
package com.test.gui;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public abstract class AbstractFoo {
    protected String fxml;
    protected String content;
    protected Stage stage;
    protected Parent root;
    
    public void initialize(String fxml, String content) {
        this.fxml = fxml;
        this.content = content;
        
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(this.getClass().getResource(fxml));
            loader.setController(this);

            try {
                this.root = loader.load();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            this.stage = new Stage();
            this.stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            this.stage.show();
        });
    }
    
    public String getContent() {
        return this.content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some insight into why you are doing this? What is the actual problem you’re trying to solve that makes you jump through all these bizarre hoops? Without that information, I don’t really see how this is useful to other users.

Comment: The use of the runLater in initialize, and the new JFXPanel created in the question but never used are both really weird things.

Comment: This also violates the principle of single responsibility. Your controller class is both acting as a controller/presenter in the usual MVC/MVP sense, but it’s also instantiating the UI and creating and showing the window, etc, which is application lifecycle functionality. I just don’t see the point of this.